# Vapor 4 Authentication Issue [User is not authenticated]

Tags: swift, authentication, vapor

I have an iOS client with OAuth 2.0 as an authenticating mechanism.

When a user signs in, I authenticate him with this method (Google sign in for example):

```
 func processGoogleLogin(request: Request, token: String) throws -> EventLoopFuture<ResponseEncodable> {
    try Google
        .getUser(on: request)
        .flatMap { userInfo in
            User
                .query(on: request.db)
                .filter(\.$email == userInfo.email)
                .first()
                .flatMap { foundUser in
                    guard let existingUser = foundUser else {
                        //creating a new user
                        return user
                            .save(on: request.db)
                            .map {
                                request.session.authenticate(user)
                                //redirecting with info
                            }
                    }
                    request.session.authenticate(existingUser)
                    //redirecting with info
                }
        }
}
```

After the login, I want to check if the user is authenticated and if I've successfully authenticated the user.
So I have an endpoint that I protect from unauthenticated users, but even after signing in, the user cannot access this endpoint as he is not authenticated.

---

Error:

```
{
"error": true,
"reason": "User not authenticated."
}
```

---

My User Model conforms to **ModelSessionAuthenticatable**.

I also use the SessionMiddleware (ImpreialController is the auth controller):

```
   let imperialController = ImperialController(sessionsMiddleware: app.sessions.middleware)
   app.middleware.use(app.sessions.middleware)
```

---

In ImperialController:

```
class ImperialController {
    private let sessionsMiddleware: Middleware
    
    init(sessionsMiddleware: Middleware) {
        self.sessionsMiddleware = sessionsMiddleware
    }
    ....
```

---

And finally the protected route:

```
let protected = app.grouped(User.guardMiddleware())

protected.get { req -> HTTPResponseStatus in
    return .ok
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that you are doing it, but just not showing it in your question. You need to create and register an instance of `SessionsMiddleware` using something like this:

```swift
app.middleware.use(SessionsMiddleware(session: MemorySessions(storage: MemorySessions.Storage())))
```

Do this before you create the instance of your controller.

EDIT in reply to OP' comment:
I normally pass the instances of the different middleware explicitly because I tend to apply subsets to groups of routes rather than all the middleware. For example:

```swift
    app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: app.directory.publicDirectory))
    app.middleware.use(SessionsMiddleware(session: MemorySessions(storage: MemorySessions.Storage())))
    app.middleware.use(User.sessionAuthenticator(.mysql))

    try app.register(collection: APIController(middleware: UserToken.authenticator()))

    var middleware: [Middleware] = [CustomMiddleware.InternalErrorMiddleware()]
    try app.register(collection: InsecureController(middleware: middleware))

    middleware.append(contentsOf: [User.redirectMiddleware(path: [C.URI.Solidus].string),
                                   User.authenticator(), User.guardMiddleware(),
                                   CustomMiddleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware()])
    try app.register(collection: CustomerController(middleware: middleware))
```

BTW, have you included my line 3 above? That may be your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this:
 app.middleware.use(SessionsMiddleware(session: MemorySessions(storage: MemorySessions.Storage())));
    let imperialController = ImperialController(sessionsMiddleware: app.sessions.middleware);
    app.middleware.use(app.sessions.middleware);
But it didn't work, is this the way you meant?

Comment: @Nathace I've edited my answer in response to your comment and hopefully suggest another cause for your problem.